# How to create list of sets with k+1 elements from list of set with k elements if order does not matter?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-mining, apriori

I am trying to implement a variant of the Apriori algorithm which involves forming lists of sets of size k+1 from lists of sets of size k. For example, if I had list [[1], [2], [3], [4]], I would like to form list [[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,3], [2,4], [3,4]] and then[[1,2,3], [1,2,4], [2,3,4]]. I have considered using a LinkedHashSet data structure to prune out repeated elements, but LinkedHashSets don't prune out cases in structure [x, y] [y, x] which I want removed. Does anyone have any suggestions or experience in stuff like this?

Thanks

Comment: Do post the code which you have tried till now while asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the sets as values in a `Hashtable` with keys consisting of the list, sorted, joined with a separator.  This will cause `[x, y]` and `[y, x]` to both be stored under the key `String.format('%d:%d', x, y)` (assuming that `x <= y`).  This will let you catch duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This will be *slow*. Try it on large data with many items. You'll run into combinatorial explosion.

There are good reasons why APRIORI sorts it's data, and why it does the more complicated (but *way* more efficient) AprioriGen method, as well as the hash tree.